# absolute positioned div floating up in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The footer of my site is a sticky footer with relative positioning. Inside I have an absolutely positioned div containing an image. The positioning works fine in every browser I've tested except safari, where the image seems to detach and "float up". Here are two screen prints, one from chrome and one from safari to illustrate the problem: http://i57.tinypic.com/256z0jb.jpg

I have been researching about this issue in stack overflow and over the internet and can't seem to find an answer. Any assistance or redirection to a link where I can find help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
footer {
background:#d4d3d3;
bottom:0;
clear:both;
display:block;
height:4em;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:-4em;
padding-top:0.5em;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
z-index:1;
}

div#image {
float:none;
position:absolute;
top:-75px;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer> 
   <div id="image"><img src="img/img1.png"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using - version 5 for PC is dead. Does it understand HTML5 `footer` element? That could be your issue. Does it fail in IE8 too?

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am using Safari 5.1.7, which is probably the issue...I'll update and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are using an older version of Safari that does not recognise HTML5 elements such as footer. I would also simplify your css as so:

```
footer {
    background: #d4d3d3;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 4em;
    margin: -4em auto 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
}

footer img.semanticnameforimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    z-index: -1;
}

<footer> 
   <img src="img/img1.png" alt="alt text for image" class="semanticnameforimage">
</footer>
```